# Zip file encryption readable by some Zip clients, not others

Tags: objective-c, zip, zlib

I'm investigating a [bug report](https://github.com/abbeycode/UnzipKit/issues/12) on my open source [UnzipKit](https://github.com/abbeycode/UnzipKit) project. Basically, when writing files encrypted with a password to a Zip file, the resulting archives are readable by some Zip clients, and not others.

UnzipKit writes the password as a UTF-8 string, using the [MiniZip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) wrapper around zlib, which only supports "Traditional PKWare Encryption", not AES. 
It's using the [`zipOpenNewFileInZip3()`](https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip/blob/7baad39186c83a3532ece99541585f46cd377325/zip.c#L1327) MiniZip function to open the file for writing.

It's readable by [BetterZip](http://macitbetter.com/) and UnzipKit on the Mac, as well as [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) on Windows. However, WinZip (Mac and Windows) and the Mac's [`unzip`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/unzip.1.html) command-line app complain about an incorrect password.

For testing purposes, I'm encrypting the files using `111111` as the password, as indicated in the bug report. I tried changing the text encoding to ASCII, and Latin 1 (CP-1252), but that didn't seem to make a difference.

I'm working on getting familiar with the way Zip files work, but this still seems mysterious to me. What could I be doing wrong to cause it to work in some clients and not in others? I would expect it to work or be broken across the board.

Here is a zip file's hex dump, that fails to unzip:

> 50 4B 03 04 14 00 01 00 08 00 B7 54 D1 46 1B B6 2D 32 2F 00 00 00 21 00 00 00 0F 00 00 00 54 65 73 74 20 46 69 6C 65 20 41 2E 74 78 74 37 52 6F F1 31 B6 6E 3D 76 CD 3A 67 0E FF 08 42 C9 4D 61 74 C1 27 DF CB BE 24 41 46 56 60 89 C2 07 97 56 C9 2A 50 80 86 15 E2 62 66 90 77 20 50 4B 01 02 00 00 14 00 01 00 08 00 B7 54 D1 46 1B B6 2D 32 2F 00 00 00 21 00 00 00 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 54 65 73 74 20 46 69 6C 65 20 41 2E 74 78 74 50 4B 05 06 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 3D 00 00 00 5C 00 00 00 00 00

This is what I get on the command line, with a return code of 82:

```
$ unzip -P 111111 PasswordProtected.zip
Archive:  PasswordProtected.zip
   skipping: Test File A.txt         incorrect password
```

**Update**

I created an archive of the same file with WinZip for Mac, with the same password on the file. This is its hex dump:

> 50 4B 03 04 14 00 03 00 08 00 27 BA 76 44 1B B6 2D 32 2F 00 00 00 21 00 00 00 0F 00 00 00 54 65 73 74 20 46 69 6C 65 20 41 2E 74 78 74 1C 68 5F 1E FF CA 3A 6C D5 B6 01 28 0F 72 83 D9 01 9B BA 87 51 50 1F 66 61 83 43 E8 64 58 B6 ED A6 F0 9B 3B 87 89 70 F2 4F D9 AB 21 6A 6A 06 50 4B 01 02 14 03 14 00 03 00 08 00 27 BA 76 44 1B B6 2D 32 2F 00 00 00 21 00 00 00 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 80 81 00 00 00 00 54 65 73 74 20 46 69 6C 65 20 41 2E 74 78 74 50 4B 05 06 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 3D 00 00 00 5C 00 00 00 00 00

The biggest difference is that the file data is completely different, meaning it was encrypted with a different key. Also, the general purpose bit flag indicates it used Maximum, rather than Normal, compression. Just in case the rest offers any clues, this is a summary of the differences, annotated with the field names [provided by the spec](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

- Local file header

  ```
  Field Name                UnzipKit Bytes  WinZip Bytes
  general purpose bit flag  01 00           03 00
  last mod file time        B7 54           27 BA
  last mod file date        D1 46           76 44
  ```
- File data

  ```
  UnzipKit
  37 52 6F F1 31 B6 6E 3D 76 CD 3A 67 0E FF 08 42 C9 4D 61 74 C1 27 DF CB BE 24 41 46 56 60 89 C2 07 97 56 C9 2A 50 80 86 15 E2 62 66 90 77 20

  WinZip
  1C 68 5F 1E FF CA 3A 6C D5 B6 01 28 0F 72 83 D9 01 9B BA 87 51 50 1F 66 61 83 43 E8 64 58 B6 ED A6 F0 9B 3B 87 89 70 F2 4F D9 AB 21 6A 6A 06
  ```
- Central directory structure

  ```
  Field Name                UnzipKit Bytes  WinZip Bytes
  version made by           00 00           14 03
  general purpose bit flag  01 00           03 00
  last mod file time        B7 54           27 BA
  last mod file date        D1 46           76 44
  external file attributes  00 00 00 00     00 00 80 81
  ```

All of the following fields match 100%:

- Local file header

  - `version to extract`
  - `compression method`
  - `crc-32`
  - `compressed size`
  - `uncompressed size`
  - `uncompressed size`
  - `extra field length`
  - `file name`
- Central directory structure

  - `version needed to extract`
  - `compression method`
  - `crc-32`
  - `compressed size`
  - `uncompressed size`
  - `file name length`
  - `extra field length`
  - `file comment length`
  - `disk number start`
  - `internal file attributes`
  - `relative offset of local header`
  - `file name`
- The entire "End of central directory record"

Comment: @MarkAdler It's using "Traditional PKWare Encryption". I've updated the question.

Comment: Can you add a short example of a zip file in hex that doesn't decode to this question?

Comment: @MarkAdler I added it. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @MarkAdler I also added an analysis of what I see compared to the hex of a file created with WinZip for Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the last parameter in your `zipOpenNewFileInZip3()` call is zero.  It is supposed to be the CRC of the file.

When a compressed entry is encrypted it is preceded by a 12-byte encryption header.  That header is composed of 10 or 11 random bytes followed by 2 or 1 bytes of the high end of that file's CRC.  The header is then encrypted using the password, and encryption continues from there on the compressed data.  (1 vs. 2 bytes is determined by the version of the zip format.)  This allows the unzipper to check the password by comparing the end of the decrypted encryption header with the CRC stored in the local header that precedes it.

What is happening with BetterZip and 7Zip is that they are simply not checking the end of the encryption header.  They then do not notice that the encryption header does not comply with the specification, and continue to correctly decrypt the compressed data.  UnZip and WinZip on the other hand detect the bug.

Comment: Yes, it is zero, but I give the CRC when calling `zipCloseFileInZipRaw()`, since it's not necessarily known up front (such as when streaming a file into the archive). Is that not meant to be supported for encrypted files?

Comment: That won't work.  The encryption needs the CRC at the start.

Comment: Great, that's good to know. I'll limit the API to non-streaming signatures, then. Thanks for the help (from a zip and zlib expert, no less)! I'll accept the answer once I verify I got it all working.

Comment: I can't find this in official docs, but it seems that many tools do something like this: if (LocalHeader.Flag and FlagDataDescriptor) <> 0 then CheckValue := (LocalHeader.ModifiedDateTime shl $10) else CheckValue := LocalHeader.CRC32;